# Can't save log file into a folder in a container using Azure function App - Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, azure, logging

I have a function app hosted in Azure using linux consumption plan.I have written my code in python, so I can't host it on a windows platform.I want to write my logs into a separate file in a folder of a specific container.

This is my specific code block.

```
today = date.today()

logging.basicConfig(filename='https://invoicecompare.blob.core.windows.net/cont-invoicecompare/{}_logs.log'.format(today),
                filemode='a',
                format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                level=logging.INFO,
                force=True)
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

> Result: Failure Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/site/wwwroot/https:/invoicecompare.blob.core.windows.net/cont-aacinvoicecompare/2023-04-10_logs.log' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 357, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 132, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked File "", line 850, in exec_module File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/site/wwwroot/BlobTrigger/**init**.py", line 17, in  logging.basicConfig(filename='https://invoicecompare.blob.core.windows.net/cont-aacinvoicecompare/{}_logs.log'.format(today), File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/**init**.py", line 2003, in basicConfig h = FileHandler(filename, mode, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/**init**.py", line 1146, in **init** StreamHandler.**init**(self, self._open()) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/**init**.py", line 1175, in _open return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,

I tried saving the log file into /temp folder.Then it gave no error.But I want to save the log file permanently.
And I can't view the /temp folder or /home/site/wwwroot/ folder because under the development tab, the advanced tools tab can't be seen.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDvpF.png)

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4567) I found that Advanced Tools (Kudu) is currently not supported for Linux Consumption plans.

Can anyone please give me a solution for this?

My purpose: Save the logs into a file and access it later.

Comment: Adding third party dependencies is not supported in linux consumption plan. Implementing the same one is possible by creating and deploying through VScode instead. @Asu

Comment: I deployed the code through VS code.But the log file is not created when trying to create it in a container.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your requirements is to monitor azure function logs using Azure diagnostics.

I have added Azure diagnostics settings from diagnostic settings of Monitoring pane.

[image]

[image]

Then I tried to access the logs from Log Analytics workspace through logs using `FunctionAppLogs` query.

[image]

you can even export the results as below

[image]

However, you can get all logs by navigating to monitor >> Run query in Application Insights where in you can export the results too.

```
requests | project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId'] | where timestamp > ago(30d) | where cloud_RoleName =~ '<FuncAPp>' and operation_Name =~ 'HttpTrigger1' | order by timestamp desc | take 20
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I want it as a code using python.